# Converting Control and Case vcf files into a format that can be processed by plink 1.9.0

Tags: case

I have two vcf files, one containing samples with TP53 mutations, and one containing samples with no TP53 mutations. The vcf without the mutations is the control and the vcf with the mutations is the case. How can I combine these two files into something that can be processed by the --assoc function in plink 1.9.0?

Answer (score 1):

I am no sure if I understand what are you trying to do but I think what you need is to merge the two files. You need to index them with tabix and then try:

```
bcftools merge file1.vcf.gz file2.vcf.gz -o merged_files.vcf.gz
```

then I would try:

```
plink --vcf merged_files.vcf.gz --assoc [params]
```

If this doesn't answer your question try to sketch what is your input and how your output VCF should look like.

Comment: Should a vcf be able to be inputted into the --assocfunction?

Comment: I would input before merging. I use [Beagle 5.2](https://faculty.washington.edu/browning/beagle/beagle.html) for inputation

Comment: So, I failed to merge the two files, but I already have a merged file with me (the case and control were filtered out of the big merged file), so I'll try inputting the large file with parameters.